# HTC One wireless hotspot not turning on

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, htc-one-x

My HTC One won't turn on its hotspot. It always displays the message:

> There is a temporary network problem that prevents the enablement of Mobile Hotspot function. Please retry later"

What can I do to turn it on?

I don't want to root my phone. The last time I tried, I crashed the phone completely

Answer (score 0):

try to reset the network settings in the reset option in the settings.